# Nginx deny if location contains

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How can I deny access to nginx if the path contains /local or /local-int to all networks except the local one?
For example https://example.com/api/local/settings. I tried this, but when accessed locally, the request goes to /etc/nginx/html/api/local/settings,and not to the desired backend

```
location = (local|local-int) {
    allow 10.150.0.0/16;
    allow 10.160.0.0/16;
    allow 10.170.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}
```

I have about 20 such sites, and I'm trying to come up with a solution that would not be tied to a specific location

I summarize: if I access a site from allowed ip, then it should show the page to which I am accessing, and if from a deny list, then 403

Config example:

```
server {
    listen          ip:80;
    listen          ip:443 ssl;

    server_name test.com;
    if_modified_since off;
   

    location /api {
        proxy_pass https://api.example.com;
    }
    location ~ (\/local) {
    allow 10.150.0.0/16;
    allow 10.160.0.0/16;
    allow 10.170.0.0/16;
    deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx takes a `=` location modifier as an exact match (docs are [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)). If you want to make a location that will catch every URI containing `/local` substring (obviously including `/local-int`), you can use a regex one:

```
location ~ /local {
    ...
}
```

The `^~` modifier makes the location block in @user973254 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72059523/7121513) (original answer version, already fixed) a prefix one with the greater priority than any regex locations, so it will overtake only the URIs starting with `/local` (obviously not including `/api/local/settings` from your example).

However if your web backend requires an additional URI processing (which is a most common case nowadays), you'll need at least to replicate your main location behavior with this new location. Fortunately, there is a way to avoid such a problems, and can be easily applied to an arbitrary number of sites as you ask for in your original question. You can check required conditions to make a decision for blocking the request or not using the (very powerful) [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block feature. And since we want to match address against a list of subnets, we will use a chain of `map` and [`geo`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) blocks. To use regexes (PRCE/PCRE2 syntax) for a `map` block match use a `~` string prefix (`~*` for case-insensitive match), strings containing some special characters (e.g. curly braces) should be single- or double-qouted. Here is a generic example (you'll need only the first line of the following `map` block to fulfill your question requirements):

```
map $uri $restricted {
    ~/local                1; # regex to match any URI containing '/local' substring
    ~^/private/            1; # regex to match any URI starting with '/private'
    ~*\.jpe?g$             1; # regex to match any URI ending with '.jpg' or '.jpeg' (case-insensitive)
    /some/protected/page/  1; # exact URI match (string isn't starting with '~')
    ... any number of additional rules here
    default                0;
}
geo $deny {
    10.150.0.0/16          0;
    10.160.0.0/16          0;
    10.170.0.0/16          0;
    default                $restricted;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($deny) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

You can swap the logic to check the URI first (it can be some performance impact since the regex matching will be performed for every request including requests from the non-restricted networks, however if the majority of requests come from public addresses, there will be no significant difference). That way you can have a common non-restricted subnes list and per-site URI lists:

```
geo $restricted {
    10.150.0.0/16          0;
    10.160.0.0/16          0;
    10.170.0.0/16          0;
    default                1;
}
map $uri $deny1 {
    ~/local                $restricted;
    default                0;
}
map $uri $deny2 {
    ~^/admin               $restricted;
    default                0;
}
server {
    server_name site1.com;
    if ($deny1) { return 403; }
    ...
}
server {
    server_name site2.com;
    if ($deny2) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

Of course, you are not limited to use 403 return code using this solution (which is the case when you are using `allow`/`deny` directives). It also has nothing to do with the famous ["If is evil"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article since this `if` is used in `server` context.

Answer (score 0):

This will simply work with both of your `locations`, since both starts with `/local`

```
location ~ (\/local) {
    allow 10.150.0.0/16;
    allow 10.160.0.0/16;
    allow 10.170.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.
```
10.160.55.133 - - [03/May/2022:21:55:57 +0300] "GET /api/local/ext/settings HTTP/1.1" 200 1225 " https://example.com/api/local/ext/settings" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/ 537.36"
95.214.55.53 - - [03/May/2022:21:56:12 +0300] "GET /api/local/ext/settings HTTP/1.1" 200 6680 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```
The second request should have blocked

Comment: @kapustactl why? second one starts with `/api`, not with `/local` as mentioned in `location {}` regular expression

Comment: so I wrote in the question that the path contains the /local, and does not start with it. The path can be /api/local, /local, /int_api/local,  , and various other variations

Comment: @kapustactl ok, sorry for misunderstanding, I've corrected my answer, please try it

Comment: with this solution i get error like in question body :)
2022/05/04 18:59:50 [error] 28123#28123: *240092 open() "/etc/nginx/html/example/int_api/local/index" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: @kapustactl this error is not related to my solution, it's your path or rewrite issue

Comment: I don't overwrite at all. I added the config I'm testing on to the question header

Comment: @kapustactl my answer matches URL `http://example.com/example/int_api/local/index`

Comment: I do not argue, but your solution prohibits traffic for hosts outside the list, but also breaks the logic for those who are on the allowed list :)